# A word for a sale that is not an installment but actually paid in full

Tags: synonyms

When you are buying something in a store you have the option to pay it in credit or debit, with or without instalments. Is there are a single word for something that is paid in full at the time of purchase?

Comment: If not paid over time, that's *paid* or *paid in full*

Comment: The only way it’s actually paid in full *at the time of purchase* is a cash sale.  Other types of sales including credit card sales or checks take time to clear even if the intent is to pay in full.

Comment: There are alternative definitions of cash; checks are often considered cash, although they take time to clear. Debit cards take only a few seconds to clear. Credit cards also clear in a few seconds; the merchant is paid at the time of purchase, although the credit card bill may be paid over time.

Comment: @Xanne - Here, for cash, I was talking about paper money and coins.  For credit cards and debit cards, it may seem like the transactions go through immediately- they certainly deduct the money right away but the merchant often has to wait several days to get the money.  https://www.creditcardprocessing.com/resource/article/long-take-merchant-receive-funds/

Comment: For what is worth, I work as a programmer and our software processes credit/debit/voucher card transactions. As such, I needed a good translation for the exact question I proposed as I didn't find any source mentioning it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really like the answers given above. For what it's worth, I suggest **lump sum**

> an amount of money that is paid at one time : a single sum of money

*The bonus is paid out in a lump sum.*

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: I really like this answer, it serves me well in the context of programming.

Answer (score 11):

"Buying something **outright**" means buying in full without any hire purchase, installment plan, or other arrangement.

[Lexico has](https://www.lexico.com/definition/outright) as one meaning of *outright* "Not by degrees or instalments." Example sentence: "they decided to buy the company outright"

[Merriam-Webster defines](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outright) it in rather formal terms as "made without encumbrance or lien".

You'll see it widely used in websites on personal finance e.g.

- https://www.drivesmart.co.uk/hpoutrightpurchasepersonal.aspx
- https://www.money.co.uk/guides/what-is-the-best-way-to-pay-for-a-new-car.htm

Answer (score 2):

Not suitable for the most *formal* contexts, but in general it's perfectly natural to say you...

> *bought it for* [*cash **on the nail***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cash%20on%20the%20nail%22) (hundreds of instances in Google Books)

> **on the nail** (informal) - *Immediately, promptly, or without delay; on the spot* <sub>[(thefreedictionary)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+nail)</sub>

Comment: Really nice to know about this one, never heard of it. Thanks.

Comment: I thought perhaps it was essentially a *British* usage, but Google Books returns a lot of hits for the collocation [*"**dollars** cash on the nail"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dollars+cash+on+the+nail%22), so that's obviously not really true.